# error: incompatible types : String cannot be converted to JSONObject url, (String) null,^

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, android-volley

[image: rror: incompatible types]

I am trying to create an app using Volley library, this app is about showing some meeting dates, but it's showing me this error whenever I am executing the app.

Comment: Can you show what line that error is on? Without that, we don't know why the error is happening

Comment: Show your line 40 please.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a String value to a JsonObject.